Google Breakpad Core Handler not working as expected with ptrace disabled
I'm trying to get valid BT from minidump when ptrace is disabled.
I tried generating the minidump using the core_handler.
https://chromium.googlesource.com/breakpad/breakpad/+/master/docs/linux_core_handler.md
This minidump <minidump.md> file that I get is converted to a core file using the minidump-2-core converter. However, when I try to load the core using gdb I just get this:
#0  0x000014ea955f0913 in ?? ()
[Current thread is 1 (LWP 58969)]
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000014ea955f0913 in ?? ()
#1  0xabababababababab in ?? ()
#2  0xabababababababab in ?? ()
#3  0xabababababababab in ?? ()
#4  0xabababababababab in ?? ()
#5  0xabababababababab in ?? ()

The same thing works with ptrace enabled. I do get a legit BT when ptrace is enabled.
Do we need any extra config to ensure that we get a valid BT from minidump when ptrace is disabled? Based on my understanding core_handler doesn't use ptrace so it should work.
If not, is there a way to get a valid minidump when ptrace is disabled?
